# Context value does not update upon theme toggling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

So I wanted to do theming based on localStorage value and colors stored in Context. Issue is that toggling does not update ThemeContext values, though it being bound with layout state (which happens to update, but I want to avoid passing color pallette down the whole tree). Below I paste the code with Context provided, the toggle button is nested deeper into the code, but it does not differ from what's in React docs:

```js
//./comps/AdminLayout.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head';
import AdminNav from './AdminNav';
import ThemeContext from '../Utils/ThemeContext';
import themes from '../Utils/ColorPalette';

export default class extends Component {
    static contextType = ThemeContext;
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            theme: themes.light,
            toggle: () => {
                this.setState({
                    theme: (window.localStorage.theme === 'dark'
                        ? themes.light
                        : themes.dark)
                });
                window.localStorage.theme = (window.localStorage.theme === 'dark' ? 'light': 'dark');
            }
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        window.localStorage.theme = 'light';
    }
    toggle() {
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <ThemeContext.Provider value={this.state}>
                <div className="layout">
                    <style jsx global>{`
                        * {
                            box-sizing: border-box;
                            font-family: sans-serif;
                            margin: 0;
                            padding: 0;
                        }
                        html, body {
                            color: ${this.context.theme.primary};
                            box-sizing: inherit;
                            background: ${this.context.theme.background};
                        }
                        a {
                            color: inherit;
                            text-decoration: none;
                        }
                        button {
                            border: none;
                        }
                    `}</style>
                    <Head>
                        <title>{this.props.title} - Next Commerce</title>
                        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
                    </Head>
                    <AdminNav />
                    {this.props.children}
                    <style jsx>{`
                    .layout {
                        display: flex;
                    }
                    `}</style>
                </div>
            </ThemeContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}
//./comps/Utils/ThemeContext.js
import React from 'react';
import themes from './ColorPalette';

const ThemeContext = React.createContext({
    theme : themes.light,
    toggle: () => {}
});

export default ThemeContext;
//Button that is supposed to toggle theme - it changes AdminLayout's state
<ThemeContext.Consumer>
    {({toggle}) => (
        <button className="btn btn-theme" onClick={toggle}>Toggle theme</button>
    )}
</ThemeContext.Consumer>
```

Is it related with Next somehow or is it me doing something wrong? Any solutions?

Just to clarify: ThemeContext.Consumer doesn't work too.